# compile and install modified kernel

Tags: grub2, kernel, compiling, kvm-virtualization

I have made some changes to the vmx.c file of the kernel. Now I am using

```
make menuconfig
```

followed by

```
make -j 5
```

command to compile the modified kernel(No errors just a warning..)
Now I am using the

```
sudo dpkg -i ../linux*.deb
```

to install the kernel. 
After installation, when I reboot and start the machine again and check the kernel version by using

```
uname -a
```

it shows that the O.S is using the old kernel but not the newly compiled and installed modified kernel.

1. Where am I going wrong ?
2. I donot see any new options in GRUB. they are the same old options, Should I see a new option in GRUB (Something like boot with new kernel?) if my modified kernel got installed properly ?

Kindly help me in this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: no new options, if you installed it correctly, grub will want to boot automatically on that one (because it's the latest). Have you generated a new vmlinuz file and `sudo update-grub` ?

Answer (score 0):

Err... AFAIK `make` command does not generate `.deb` file, it just compiles source files. So

```
sudo dpkg -i ../linux*.deb
```

just installed old kernel again.

To generate binary package you should use `fakeroot debian/rules binary`. There is no need to run `make` before this command as it will do all the actions in one pass.

To have `debian/rules` file, you have to [debianize your sources](https://wiki.debian.org/IntroDebianPackaging) or get sources with `apt-get source linux`.

Comment: so after `make -j 5` I should use `fakeroot debian/rules binary` to create binary package and then use `sudo dpkg -i ../linux*.deb ` to install it ...Right ?

Comment: You have to sure that you have `debian/rules` file. If not, retrieve sources with `apt-get source ...` and use the command. It will configure, make and make install binary files into package which you will install by `dpkg -i`. There is no need to run `make` before this command.

Comment: I already have the source files and I am using the above commands while I am in the source folder. :( 
Also when I used `fakeroot debian/rules binary`, I was getting `/usr/bin/fakeroot: line 178: debian/rules: No such file or directory`

Comment: How did you retrieve the sources?

Comment: I have downloaded it (version 3.13.6) from kernel.org

Comment: I updated my answer, please check.